# What is causing the math domain error?

Tags: python

Here is the code that I have written to calculate the altitude of a model rocket. On line 49 I am getting an math domain error message. Here is a link to the error message:

[image: 1]

```
from math import *

motor_type = raw_input("What is the motor letter")

b4 = { "th" : 13.2, "i" : 5.00, "ti" : 0.8}
b6 = { "th" : 12.1, "i" : 5.00, "ti" : 0.8}
c = { "th" : 15.3, "i" : 10.00, "ti" : 1.6}
d = { "th" : 32.9, "i" : 20.00, "ti" : 1.6}
e = { "th" : 25.0, "i" : 30.00, "ti" : 2.8} 

    #######################################################
a1 = b4["th"]
a2 = b4["i"]
a3 = b4["ti"]

b1 = b6["th"]
b2 = b6["i"]
b3 = b6["ti"]

c1 = c["th"]
c2 = c["i"]
c3 = c["ti"]

d1 = d["th"]
d2 = d["i"]
d3 = d["ti"]

e1 = e["th"]
e2 = e["i"]
e3 = e["ti"]

    #######################################################
def get_altitude(th, i, ti):
    Cd = float(.075)#drag coefficient = 0.75 for average rocket
    rho = float(1.22)#air density = 1.22 kg/m3
    g = float(9.81)#acceleration of gravity = 9.81 m/s2
    v = float(0.0)#burnout velocity in m/s
    y1 = float(0.0)#altitude at burnout
    yc = float(0.0)#coasting distance
    ta = float(0.0)#coasting time => delay time for motor
    m = float(raw_input("What is the mass in Kg of the rocket with the    motor loaded ")) #rocket mass in kg
    a = pi * (((float(int(raw_input("What is the diameter of the rocket   body in cm")))) / 200)**2) #rocket cross-sectional area in m2
    #######################################################
    k = rho*Cd*a*0.5
    q = (th - m * g) / k
    x = ((2*k*q)/ m)
    v = q * ((1 - exp(-x * ti))/(1 + exp(-x * ti)))
    yc = (m / (2*k)) * log((m*g+k * (v**2))/(m*g))
    y1 = (-m/(2*k))*log((th - m * g - k * (v**2)) / (th - (m * g)))
    qa = sqrt(m*g/k)
    qb = sqrt(g*k/m)
    ta = atan(v/qa) / qb
    altitude = y1 + yc 
    print "Time from burnout to apogee"
    print ta
    print "Max altitude"
    print altitude 

if motor_type == "b4":
    get_altitude(a1, a2, a3)
elif motor_type == "b6":
    get_altitude(b1, b2, b3)
elif motor_type == "c":
    get_altitude(c1, c2, c3)
elif motor_type == "d":
    get_altitude(d1, d2, d3)
elif motor_type == "e":
    get_altitude(e1, e2, e3)
```

Answer (score 2):

On line 49 you're performing a `log` operation, but `log` is only defined for numbers greater than 0. So, you get a math domain error. Check your values.

As one random example of purposely causing this error....

Let's say I enter "b4" for the motor enter 0.0005 and then 1 for the mass in kg and diameter in cm respectively the value of the expression in your `log` would be -3.6 * 10^6 and the log of this isn't defined.

Also, one minor thing I noticed just glossing over your code doing `float(0.0)` for your variables is unnecessary 0.0 is already a floating point number. Likewise, for the other floats.

Comment: Thank you. When you say check values, do you mean put in a check to make sure values are greater than 0?

Comment: Yes otherwise a math domain error will be raised as log is only defined for values greater than zero